# How can I fix my social problems in Whiterun?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm leader of the companions and I killed an innocent citizen with Farkos following me. Now, if he notices me, he talks to me as if I talk to him and I want to know how to stop it.

I'm also currently hated in Whiterun because I murdered almost everyone there.

I also killed Milo's mom, does that mean she's now an orphan?

If you can help with any of these problems I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: So you killed everyone and can not figure out why everyone in Whiterun hates you??? Um.. cause you killed everyone?

Comment: I'm not even sure if this question is answerable but I tried to rescue it best as I could.

Comment: What exactly you **want** to happen? You wish everyone to live again and love you?

Answer (score 4):

This is my serious answer: Reload to a previous save or start the game over.

If you want to try to play with your choices you have made, either stay out of whiterun, or try to pay a guard your bounty.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why Farkas follows and keeps trying to talk to you is that you have a bounty at one of the holds.

Pay off all of your bounties in all of the holds and Farkas should stop talking to you. I had the same problem until I paid the bounty because the companions have the guard AI. However, they can't arrest you, so they get stuck in an infinite loop.

If you are spotted committing a murder, then the people who saw you will not like you; therefore, if you kill everyone, then everybody who is still alive will hate you and may send hired thugs.

Finally, having killed Milo's mom, you can technically consider her an "orphan." However, she will not go to the orphanage in Riften and will still talk as if her mom was still around (if you get her trust back up).